# Problems with installing ggplot2 and interactions in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, interaction

I wanted to use the packages ggplot2 and interactions. I first installed interactions and then ggplot2. However I got error messages because I did not have the newest version of ggplot2.
I tried updating ggplot2, which repeatedly did not work. So I deinstalled it and tried reinstalling it. Now I can't even install it again and "interactions" doesn't work either.
I don't understand what I did wrong, because I could install it the first time.

Ihis is the error message I get, when trying to install ggplot now:

```
> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently
> installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of
> Rtools before proceeding:
> 
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/ Installing package into
> ‘C:/Users/ErikNB/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’ (as ‘lib’ is
> unspecified) also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘lifecycle’,
> ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’
> 
> 
>   There are binary versions available but the source versions   are
> later:
>           binary source needs_compilation   
>cli        3.2.0  3.6.1              TRUE   
>lifecycle  1.0.1  1.0.3             FALSE   
>rlang      1.0.2  1.1.1.            TRUE   
>vctrs      0.4.1  0.6.3              TRUE   
>ggplot2    3.3.5  3.4.2.            FALSE 
> 
>   Binaries will be installed trying URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/cli_3.2.0.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 1255499 bytes (1.2 MB)
> downloaded 1.2 MB
> 
> trying URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rlang_1.0.2.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 1718546 bytes (1.6 MB)
> downloaded 1.6 MB
> 
> trying URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/vctrs_0.4.1.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 1569486 bytes (1.5 MB)
> downloaded 1.5 MB
> 
> package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked package
> ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked package ‘vctrs’
> successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> 
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>   C:\Users\ErikNB\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpuga9xh\downloaded_packages
> installing the source packages ‘lifecycle’, ‘ggplot2’
> 
> trying URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.3.tar.gz' Content
> type 'application/x-gzip' length 106854 bytes (104 KB) downloaded 104
> KB
> 
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.4.2.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3153811 bytes (3.0 MB)
> downloaded 3.0 MB
> 
> * installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
> ** Paket 'lifecycle' erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
> ** using staged installation
> ** R
> ** inst
> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Fehler in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :   
> namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required Ruft
> auf: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace ->
> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace Ausführung angehalten ERROR: lazy
> loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
> * removing 'C:/Users/ErikNB/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/lifecycle'
> * restoring previous 'C:/Users/ErikNB/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/lifecycle' Warning in
> install.packages :   installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero
> exit status
> * installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
> ** Paket 'ggplot2' erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
> ** using staged installation
> ** R
> ** data
> *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
> ** inst
> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Fehler in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :   
> namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required Ruft
> auf: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace ->
> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace Ausführung angehalten ERROR: lazy
> loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
> * removing 'C:/Users/ErikNB/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ggplot2' Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had
> non-zero exit status
```

this is the output i get from `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.5 tools_4.0.5
```

1. I installed rtools. However the error saying that rtools is needed didn't disappear.
2. I tried updating rslang. however every time I tried to update it, it just shows the old version afterwards. I'm too scared to uninstall it, because of what happened with ggplot2.

Comment: Can you verify the version of "rlang"installed?  It looks like you need version 1.1.1 installed first.  You may need to restart R to ensure the most recent version is loaded.

Comment: i have the wrong version of "rlang". however i cannot update it. i tried to do it repeatedly by hand and with the green update button, but it just stays with my current version. that is the same thing that happened with ggplot2 before i deinstalled it. i also tried to install some other packages and that did not work either. i have no idea what i did, i could install and load packages without problem a few hours ago.

Comment: It will help if you edit the question and add the results from this command: `sessionInfo()`

Comment: I'm sorry, i already restarted r and my computer a few times, so i hope this is still helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LEK, it seems from here:

> removing 'C:/Users/ErikNB/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ggplot2'

that you are not using the latest version of R itself, which is actually 4.3.1   --->   https://www.r-project.org/

I would start from scratch by installing the latest version of R, if 4.0 is not a must, and then trying again to install `interactions` and `ggplot2` packages.

Answer (score 0):

Like Fede B said: I needed the newest version of R. Just installing it from Rstudio did not work, i had to deinstall all older versions of r before i could use the new one. I had to reinstall almost all of my packages, but i had no problem with "ggplot2" and "interactions" anymore! Thank you.